# Определить позицию страницы

Tags: jquery

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с помощью `jQuery` определить позицию страницы?

Задача следующая: есть `div`, который должен принимать свойство `fixed` при сдвиге страницы вниз на `150px`.

Заранее благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так

```
$(window).scroll(function(){                              // отслеживаем событие
   if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= 150 ){                   // ставим условие
      $('#div_to_fixed').css('position','fixed');         // определяем действие
   }
});
```

Про [.scroll](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F_scroll)

Comment: так и сделал! спасибо за советы!

Answer (score 3):

Если вы про скроллинг страницы вниз то думаю поможет это - [scrollTop](http://jquery-docs.ru/css/scrolltop/)

Answer (score 2):

Добавляем class="fixed" в элемент с id="header" если ниже 150px, если выше class="fixed" убираем:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var h = $('#header');
   if ( $(window).scrollTop() > 150 ){
      h.addClass('fixed');
   } else {
      h.removeClass('fixed');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем давай класс если можно передавать свойство?

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var h = $('#header');
   if ( $(window).scrollTop() > 150 ){
      h.style.position = 'fixed';
   } else {
      h.style.position = '';
   }
});
```

Comment: Как можно понять первое предложение в вашем ответе?